# Connecting to SQL Server instance without giving port

Tags: sql-server-2008, port, ssms

I have recently added another SQL Server 2008 instance to a server and want to be able to connect to without having to specify the new port number in SSMS. Is this possible?

I can connect if I use `MyServer, 2434\Staging`

but fails when I use `MyServer\Staging`

Is there a setting that I need to change or alias to setup?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sounds like the [SQL Server Browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx) isn't running on `MyServer`

Comment: @MartinSmith it is and I just restarted it to be sure. I can connect to the default instance no problem, its the new named instance I am having issues with. Could it be an issue that the default port is pointed to a SQL 2005 Instance?